# ruby - equivalent of `gem open` for core libraries

Tags: ruby

I can `gem open #{gem_name}` (command line) to see the source of installed gems. But how do I view the source of e.g. `openssl` which is in ruby core?

(Without going to the [github repo](https://github.com/ruby/openssl)... is there a command to view it locally?)

Comment: The original title was "ruby open core library source", which was rejected for not meeting quality standards - I think a false positive in this case?

Comment: You could re-install the built-in gem, e.g. `gem install openssl -v '2.0.5'`

Comment: I found `vim ~/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/` to be a passable workaround; you can find YOUR folder by running `which ruby` then if you climb up folders and then down into any likely folders you can find the source

Comment: That will just give you the [`lib`](https://github.com/ruby/openssl/tree/master/lib) directory, i.e. the Ruby files. You won't see the gem's [`ext`](https://github.com/ruby/openssl/tree/master/ext/openssl) directory, i.e. the C source and header files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one. The reason most probably is that gems shipped with Ruby aren't treated in a different way than the core code. That said, the libraries are [located under `ext/`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/trunk/ext).

If you want to find specific code (assuming it's Ruby and not C), you can always do

```
foo.method(:bar).source_location
Foo.instance_method(:bar).source_location
```

Comment: `source_location` returns nil? `OpenSSL::Cipher.instance_method(:key_len).source_location`

Comment: @xxjjnn as I said, as long as it's Ruby and not C code.